# Windows Hello Identify configured sign in type (Hello Face/Hello Fingerprint)-UWP

Tags: windows, authentication, uwp, biometrics, windows-hello

I want to implement Biometric access to my UWP app and want to get which sign-in option is configured by the user(Hello Face/Hello Fingerprint).

[image]

Is there any way I can get the user-configured sign-in type?

**If not I can go to an option like this.**

I can check whether the fingerprint is enabled using

```
var ucvAvailability = await Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerifier.CheckAvailabilityAsync();
```

Is there any way to check if the user has enabled hello Face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can get the user-configured sign-in type?

No, UWP does not have such APIs that could access the system setting like sign-in options.

> Is there any way to check if the user has enabled hello Face?

No, there is no way in UWP to check if the customer enabled Hello face. UWP could only check if the device enables Windows Hello using [KeyCredentialManager.IsSupportedAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.keycredentialmanager.issupportedasync?view=winrt-22621). More information here: [Implementing Windows Hello](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport#3-implementing-windows-hello)